# Audio Interface Drivers not compatible with Ubuntu. Suddenly stopped working

Tags: drivers

I restarted my computer after having Ubuntu running for the past day perfectly fine

I just restarted and now there's no audio and it's not recognizing my speakers anymore

I have a behringer 404HD and the audio drivers do not within Ubuntu or Linux they only work  in windows 10

I'm not sure how to fix this

when I installed Ubuntu I had clicked the install 3rd party software option

Then when I was configuring Ubuntu I did the auto delete command and I'm wondering if that removed the audio drivers

I'm new to Ubuntu and LInux in general

Comment: When dual-booting with Windows, disabling its Fast Startup "feature" is a must. So, before anything else do that and shutdown Windows. I don't know what "auto delete command"you actually used. If it was `sudo apt autoremove` then no, it has nothing to do with drivers.

Comment: @ChanganAuto fast boot is disabled already

Comment: Fast Boot (UEFI) is also recommended to be disabled but that has nothing to do with Fast Startup (Windows).

Comment: @ChanganAuto sorry yes, Fast Boot UEFI and Fast startup Windows are both disabled. The issue is entirely with Ubuntu.

Comment: Some reading: https://linuxmusicians.com/viewtopic.php?t=17231 https://discourse.ardour.org/t/using-a-behringer-audio-interface-and-guitarix/102002/8

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what happened but,

I unplugged the cable about 50 times and on the 50th time it just started working again

no clue what happened